# Android typed controls instead of findViewById

Tags: android

Is it somehow possible that instead of:

`Button btnNextWord = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnNextWord);`

Eclipse automatically generates for me something like:

`Button btnNextWord = this.btnNextWord;`


or

`Button btnNextWord = R.id.getBtnNextWord(this);`

??

Comment: Absolutely possible with Android Extensions in Kotlin. Otherwise, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because what you're doing in requesting a reference to a child element that has a certain name and Eclipse isn't actually loading in the layout xml so it can't know what is in it.

Comment: Well, it's obviously loading layout xml to parse elements (in order to generate R.id.lblNextWord)... why could it parse type of element and wrap it in R class?

Comment: It can't cast the View to the right type and return it because then you would need to have method signatures that differed only by return type, (i.e. public Button findById(int id) and public CheckBox findById(int id)) which is not allowed in a statically typed language like Java. Also it is not possible to dynamically add methods to the Android API's based on the names that you give your widgets.

These things would be possible in a functional scripting language that is dynamically typed, like Lua or Python.

Comment: "Well, it's obviously loading layout xml to parse elements". No, it isn't. It is reading in the source to the R.java class in your gen/ directory. That file is generated by the aapt tool, IIRC.

Comment: :)

I never said it needs to have unique method name - it can have get<uniqueControlId>(context) with typed return value (it can be property).

In nutshell, I don't mind that much about way it's implemented, just I don't wish to _findViewById_ on every 5 lines, and see no reason why those controls can't be exposed as typed properties...

So, anyone else - any support for this in Android/Eclipse, or I need to write add-in for Eclipse/extend framework?

Comment: No, no support for this in Android or Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late response but it might help someone who read.

You can use the [android annotations library](http://androidannotations.org/) for doing something similar to what you want.

As you can see on their page, you can write a field in the code like this:

```
@ViewById
ListView bookmarkList;
```

The library will findById an item with id R.id.bookmarkList and cast it to ListView.

Or you can use the annotation like this

```
@ViewById(R.id.myTextView)
TextView someName;
```

if you want to give a better name to the field.

DISCLAIMER:
I never used the library so I'm not sure whether you can use just that annotation or you're bound to use their whole set of annotations.